# How to use the for loop, the IN operator in same mysqli_query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, in-operator

I want to create mysqli_query wish will return a database tuples basing on a list of ids.

In **SQL**, the query will be as following:

```
SELECT * FROM `tale_name` WHERE `id` in(1,2,3,4);
```

Supposing that the ids are putted in a PHP array called **$id_array**, so how can I write the same query but in a **PHP code**?

As a start, I tried the following code (but I know that it's not true):

```
mysqli_query($this->conn, "SELECT * FROM `tale_name` WHERE
 `id` in (".for ($i = 0; $i < count($id_array); $i++){ echo $id_array[$i]}.")");
```

It seems like the for loop cant be combined with a mysqli_query in PHP... 
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php).

Usage: `string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )`

```
mysqli_query($this->conn, "SELECT * FROM `tale_name` WHERE `id` in (". implode(',', $id_array) .")");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `echo` function is for outputting. You'd need to build a variable and then concatenate that to your string. You should cast it to an `int` at minimum to prevent SQL injections, the best practice though is to parameterize your query.

```
$ids ='';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($id_array); $i++){ 
        $ids .= ((int)$id_array[$i]) . ', ';
}
$ids = rtrim($ids, ', ');
echo "SELECT * FROM `tale_name` WHERE `id` in ({$ids})";
```

Parameterized version:

```
$placeholders = str_repeat('?, ', count($id_array));
$placeholders = rtrim($placeholders, ', ');
echo "SELECT * FROM `tale_name` WHERE `id` in ({$placeholders})";
```

Then use `prepare`, `bind_param`, and `execute` on that query.